# Is it legally possible to install Windows 7/8/10 Home/Pro into a VM on a rented virtual server

Tags: windows-7, linux, windows-8, virtualbox, windows-10

I'm planning on build an infrastructure for myself and possibly sharing it with others, which includes a few server applications which I currently run on my own PC.

- git server : GitBlit runs on linux so it's okay
- agile/ticket management :  kanboard this just needs a webserver, should work under linux as well
- file sharing, this is also pretty standard so no problem here
- build server : Jenkins ci

However the build server will need to build windows apps mostly, I can opt for cross compiling or some other workaround that doesn't involve an actual windows install however I would like to consider that as the last option.

I've considered mac development and dropped it since, it obviously needs a real mac, that is the best option, so in the case of windows I'm considering the same thing, getting a legal copy and installing it on a server with a linux distro.

The question is that is it legal to install a legit copy of windows ( 7/8/10 ) that is intended for personal use ( home or pro version ) on a rented virtual server as a VM.

So the scenario is that I rent a virtual server like this one : https://www.hetzner.de/en/hosting/produkte_vserver/cx20 with a linux distro.

Then I will install Virtual Box on the server and install my windows copy on a Virtual Box VM.

I guess there is a reason that Windows Server editions exist and I wonder whenever this kind of setup is legal or not taking into account the fact that the Windows installed on the VM will not be accessible from the outside world since it will only work as a slave for Jenkins to do jobs that need Windows platform.

Comment: Why don't you ask your hosting provider? Remember that your server is already virtualized so don't expect good performance even if it works.

Comment: Indeed, physical machine -> Virtual linux -> Virtual Box -> Windows... how about just rent a (virtual) windows server (if they exist)?

Comment: I guessed the performance would be poor, however I dont thinkg as an issue, Windows Server editions exist but you have to pay per month versus buying a windows home edition once.

Comment: As far as I know - Windows 10 Home and Pro are meant to be installed on real hardware. The Enterprise version is available through Volume Licensing and could be also installed on Virtual Machines with limitations. see [Win 10 Volume Licensing](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/Licensing/product-licensing/windows10.aspx) and [Windows Desktop OS for Virtual Machines](http://download.microsoft.com/download/9/8/D/98D6A56C-4D79-40F4-8462-DA3ECBA2DC2C/Licensing_Windows_Desktop_OS_for_Virtual_Machines.pdf)

Comment: [What is the place to ask about legal issues associated with using software?](http://meta.superuser.com/q/5908/172747)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is legally possible.  You need to be aware that if you get an OEM version of the OS you can't (according to the EULA, and ignoring that this has never been challenged in court and may not be enforceable) move it to another server - which means that an OEM version is not legal if your provider may change the underlying hardware - as stupid as this sounds !

How do I know ?   I recently went round-and-round in circles speaking to Microsoft and the importer to try get a Windows 7 Pro license for a VM.  As this is not possible (unless you get an OEM version with restrictions and unless you purchase a copy of 7 Pro online from old stock !)

Comment: Any (retail) version of Windows 7 actually would have been fine.  Windows can be installed on a virtual or physical machine.  Its entirely up to you to follow the license, a retail license can be transferred to different machines, where as an OEM license is locked to that single OEM machine in most cases (i.e. except for those regions where it is allowed).

Comment: Correct - except I need Windows 7 Pro, and you can't  buy a new retail license the (New Zealand) distributor or most computer stores any more.  The terms of the EULA for the OEM version apparently says you can't shift between machines)

Comment: A retail license; sure you can; that's the difference between OEM and retail licenses

Answer (score 0):

If you can find a service provider that will let you use your own licensing then yes, you can provided the license is currently not in use on another PC. Although in the scenario you mentioned, it is not advised to run multiple layers of virtualisation.

You would need to NAT the connection from the Linux VM to the Windows VM if the Linux system has a single public IP address allocated. If it has multiple then yes yould bridge it, but no one should ever expose a workstation to the internet by giving it a public IP.

IMHO, save yourself the headache and opt-in for a Windows Server. Yes they do cost a bit more but it works a hell of a lot better.

References:
I am a member of the Microsoft Authorised Refurbisher program and as such deal with 100's of licenses daily. I also posess a Diploma in IT (Network Administration).